# Is this a Conditional Probability?

Tags: probability, statistics

[image]

I am very confused. Is the highlighted $ P(\text{Graduated} \cap \text{Studied})$ or $ P(\text{Graduated} \mid \text{Studied})$

Answer (score 3):

The highlighted part is about $P(\text{graduated}\mid\text{studied})$.  If it had been about $P(\text{graduated} \cap \text{studied})$, it would have said "It is also known that $85\%$ of all students study and graduate" or something to that effect.

The final question is about $P(\text{studied}\mid\text{graduated})$.

Answer (score 2):

You have to parse the phrase: 85% OF (all students who study) (will graduate):
that says $P(\text{Will graduate} \mid \text{Study}) = 0.85$.

$P(\text{Will graduate} \cap \text{Study}) = 0.85$ would be 
"85% OF (all students) (study AND will graduate)".

Answer (score 2):

(This is a hint rather than an answer)

Here are the survey's results:
$$
\text{of all students} \begin{cases}
  75\% \text{ study} & 
    \begin{cases}
      \color{red}{ 85\% \text{ will graduate}} \\
      15\% \text{ will not}
    \end{cases} \\
  25\% \text{ do not} & 
    \begin{cases}
      35\% \text{ will graduate} \\
      65\% \text{ will not}
    \end{cases}
\end{cases}
$$

with the red part corresponding to the sentence marked with yellow.

How many students will graduate from all of them?

How many of those graduating studied?